# Is there a way to turn off the "iCloud Drive isn't compatible with Mavericks" errors?

Tags: macos, icloud

I installed Yosemite on one of my machines (and uninstalled it a short time later).

Now, running Mavericks, every time I open a program that uses iCloud (like Numbers), I'm greeted with this message.

[image]

After clicking OK, I can still read documents stored on iCloud, I really can't see any functionality differences. After I pick a file, I get the same dialog box again, and click OK again, and I can edit and save my file.

This is extremely obnoxious.

I would guess that I can't convert my account to non-iCloud Drive, which is fine, I don't really depend on "iCloud" for anything.

My question is, how can I get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guesswork, but the bad news is you should have switched it off before reverting, if at all possible.

Looking through the various QAs at Apple forums would tend to lead to the conclusion that once you have upgraded to iCloud Drive it cannot be reverted. You may be able to switch it off from https://icloud.com but I can't test as I have never enabled it on my machines.

Apple have never been too concerned about people wanting to rewind.

General [iCloud Drive](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201104) info from Apple doesn't cover it, nor does the [switching off iCloud Drive FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH19001)

Comment: Ok, then the solution is probably install yosemite again or find a mac that has it running, and turn it off. I didn't use yosemite long enough to notice that there was an Off button (I was too busy not being able to read anything in helvetica).

Comment: First Mac OS since System 6.0.7 that I didn't upgrade to on day 1. So far, I'm not in any hurry.

Comment: I know what you mean. My first Mac was my Dad's Mac Plus. The icons in yosemite remind me of those days.

Comment: we'll get those black parallel lines in the title bars back by 10.11, I'm sure; retro-style. Either that or it will all just be 25% grey with indistinguished blobs you have to guess the meaning of. I actually like skeuomorphism - if the alternative is Win8 kiddie graphics.